# Android: How to handle "backpress-key" event when context menu is opened

Tags: android, contextmenu, onkeydown, onbackpressed

I have context menu in activity in my app:

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_main_menu, menu);
}

    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    contextMenuOpened = false;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.get_image_from_gallery:
            startGalleryPicker();
            break;
        case R.id.get_image_from_camera:
            startCamera();
            break;
        case R.id.cancel:
            break;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

The problem is when I open this context menu I cann't catch backpressed-key event in my activity: logs in overriding methods **dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event), onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event), onBackPressed()** are empty.

I know that in an activity there is a callback for the event "context menu is closed" - **onContextMenuClosed(Menu menu)**, but I need to handle backpressed-key event itself and do it in that moment when context menu is opened.
How can I do it?

Comment: Did you find the solutions ?

Comment: No, unfortunately...